# Using LibTiff with Delphi

Tags: delphi, tiff, libtiff

I'd like to use LibTiff with XE3 to access image meta data information from TIFF files.

I need to find the number of pages inside tiff and their sizes. 
I suggested LibTiff because I need the fastest possible implementation of reading tiff image meta data.

The only link I have found is not working anymore:
http://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/delphi.html

Comment: Did you try contacting awaresystems's website operator?

Comment: Also, I found out what I have a copies of both distributions, not sure if redistribution allowed, tho.

Answer (score 3):

OK, Internet Archive has returned back to operational state, and here is your download:

> [LibTiffDelphi, full version. Large download (approx 1.39 megabyte), includes Debug and Release versions](http://web.archive.org/web/20070202123132/http://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/delphi/LibTiffDelphi_Full.zip)

Comment: The associated webpage: http://web.archive.org/web/20070202114225/http://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/delphi.html

Answer (score 1):

Well, the download links at that site do appear to be down. You could try downloading from here instead: http://www.vdebris.comli.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/libtiffdelphi_3_9_1.rar

I think you could use Mike Lischke's [GraphicEx](http://www.lischke-online.de/index.php/libs/graphicex-library) to solve your problem. The `TImageProperties` record that is made available by the `TGraphicExGraphic` class appears to have what you need.

Comment: NB: this is Release distribution of library.

Answer (score 0):

found that code working with *.tif and used graphics +  lib for solution building [TIF SPLITTER](http://sourceforge.net/p/tiffsplitdemo/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/Unit_TIFFSPLITTER.pas)
not sure if it helps to solve your problem